# Register pointer in creating threads in xv6

Tags: c, multithreading, x86, cpu-registers, xv6

I want to create a thread in xv6 by using a system call "clone()", but I am confused about the stack creation, since if I want to create a thread, I need to create the corresponding register pointer such like ebp, esp, eip. But I don't know how to set the value of these register pointer.

Here is a code of clone() in xv6, I don't know why we need to set the value of the register pointer like this.......

```
int clone(void(*fcn)(void*), void *arg, void*stack){

  int i, pid;
  struct proc *np;
  int *ustack = stack + PGSIZE - sizeof(void*);
  //allocate process.
  if((np=allocproc()) == 0)
    return -1;

  //copy process state from p
  np->pgdir = proc->pgdir;
  np->sz = proc->sz;
  np->parent = 0;
  np->pthread = proc;
  *np->tf = *proc->tf;
  np->ustack = stack;

  //initialize stack variables 
  //void *stackArg, *stackRet;
  //stackRet = stack + PGSIZE -2*sizeof(void*);
  //*(uint *)stackRet = 0xffffffff;

  //stackArg = stack + PGSIZE -sizeof(void*);
  //*(uint *)stackArg = (uint)arg;
  *ustack = (int) arg;
  *(ustack - 1) = 0xffffffff;
  *(ustack - 2) = 0xffffffff;


  //Set stack pinter register
  np->tf->eax = 0;
  np->tf->esp = (int) ustack - sizeof(void*);
  np->tf->ebp = np->tf->esp;
  np->tf->eip = (int)fcn;

  for(i = 0; i < NOFILE; i++) {
    if(proc->ofile[i])
      np->ofile[i] = filedup(proc->ofile[i]);
  }

  np->cwd = idup(proc->cwd);
  np->state = RUNNABLE;
  safestrcpy(np->name, proc->name, sizeof(proc->name));
  pid = np->pid;
  return pid;

}
```

Comment: `clone()` is Linux- (and apparently xv6-) specific.  If xv6 has pthreads then I would strongly recommend using that interface instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set these registers -- clone sets them for you.  You need to provide a function (which clone uses to initialize ip) and a stack (which clone uses to initialize sp).

The function pointer is pretty straight-forward (its just a C function pointer), but the stack is trickier.  For the `clone` implementation you show, you need to allocate some memory and provide a pointer `PGSIZE` below the *end* of that block.  Linux's clone call is similar, but slightly different (you need to provide a pointer to the end of the block).  If you want to catch stack overflows, you'll need to do more work (probably allocating a read/write protected guard page below the stack).

Comment: I know how to use this system call clone() but I am confused about the register pointer in this function, and I want to know why they can be set like this

Comment: I don't understand your question then -- clone sets up the thread's registers for the new thread based on the arguments you give it.  It needs to set up the thread's registers so that your function will be called when the scheduler switches to the new thread.

Comment: For example I don't know why the np->tf->eax is equal to 0, I think it should be equal to the ebb

Comment: typo: ebp not ebb

Comment: eax is ignored on calling a function in the normal x86/C calling convertions, so it doesn't really matter what it is set to.

Comment: what about the other pointers, why they are assigned like this? I try to revise the value assigned to these pointers, it turn out to be some error during test.

Comment: esp needs to point at the stack, where the function can find its argument (at esp+4), and allocate space for locals and call other functions.  eip needs to point at the first instruction in the function, which is what a C function pointer normally points at (this is somewhat compiler dependent, but pretty much all x86 C compilers are the same).  Other registers don't really matter to the C calling conventions.

Comment: so why the ESP need to minus sizeof(void*)? I think it is just equal to stack+PGSIZE which points the beginning of the stack

Comment: So that the argument `arg` is at `dword ptr [esp + 4]`.  It also needs free space below esp, as the stack grows downwards on x86.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helps a lot, the last question, what is the 0xffffffff, the manual says it is a fake return PC, why it is placed next to the arg?

Comment: @ZhengYuan, the pc needs a place to jump to when it is done executing the last instruction in the function. So `0xffffffff` is the dummy instruction to execute. In reality you should call exit inside the function to properly exit the thread otherwise executing instruction `0xffffffff`, leads to some issues

Answer (score 1):

Of all the register values you set, the only useful ones are:

**eip** - Tells the thread where to start executing from when it returns to userspace

**esp** - This is points to the top of the stack. This means that if you did this right, 4 bytes stored at the top of the stack should contain your return address

---

**eax** is not really useful here seeing as the thread jumps to a new context and not the one where it was created. Otherwise, *eax* will store the return value of the last system call. See the implementation of `fork` if you are still confused about this one.

**ebp** is not manipulated by you, but rather by the x86 function call conventions and is usually set to the value of *esp* when the function is called. As such you will usually see this sort of thing in the disassembly of most function calls

```
push ebp      ; Preserve current frame pointer
mov ebp, esp  ; Create new frame pointer pointing to current stack top
```

*ebp* is also useful for stack tracing because it stores the top of the previous function's stack before it is then changed to point to the current stack top

---

You don't need this `*(ustack - 2) = 0xffffffff;`